# How to create window event listener in react component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a simple react component for my app, I would like to add resize function using window add event listener

Here is my solution

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class thankyoupayment extends Component {

    const resizeWindow = () =>{
        console.log('Resize me');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeWindow);
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <VideoContainer>
                    <video></video>
            </VideoContainer>
        );
    }
}

const VideoContainer =styled.div`
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
`
```

Unfortunately when I run I am gettin the following error

```
Unexpected token (8:10)
```

What do I need to change to solve the problem? React Newbie as hell

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the Class name should be capitalized:

```
class Thankyoupayment extends Component {
```

Secondly, you can't use `const` as a Class method:

```
resizeWindow = () => {
```

Comment: now I am getting the following error `react\resources\js\pages\Thankyou\thankyoupayment.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (8:17):` what do I needs to change?

Comment: @user9964622 Oh, seems like you don't have babel that will compile yet experimental class fields. Try to add babel or a specified babel extension. You can also change that arrow function into a es5 function (`handleResize() { ... }`) but then you will probably have to bind it inside constructor.

Comment: now no errors but when I try to resize the window there is no `console.log('resize me')`;

Comment: @user9964622 Just bind it inside constructor `constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
}`